# Python BERTopic 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python-3.x, bert-language-model, transformer-model, topic-modeling

I am trying to replicate the Topic Modeling exercise from this article titled [NLP Tutorial: Topic Modeling in Python with BerTopic](https://hackernoon.com/nlp-tutorial-topic-modeling-in-python-with-bertopic-372w35l9). The article comes from the website HackerNoon if you'd prefer to find it yourself. All the code used is clearly written in that article. There is also a link to the free data used in the example in the article.

I am using Python 3.10.12 and Jupyter notebook. Following the example:

```
!pip install bertopic
!pip install bertopic[visualization]

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from bertopic import BERTopic

df = pd.read_csv("~/tokyo_2020_tweets.csv", engine='python') 
df = df[0:6000]

model = BERTopic(verbose=True)
docs = df.text.to_list()
topics, probabilities = model.fit_transform(docs)
```

When I run that last line, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I am following the steps exactly, so I am not sure what's going wrong (I am new in Python). What causes this error and how do I fix it?